# Sum associative array key values and group it by key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table as follows :

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <th>PRODUCT</th>
      <th>QUANTITY</th>
      <th>AREA</th>
      <th>PRICE</th>
      <th>TOTAL</th>
   <tr>
      <td id="name">SWEETS</td>
      <td id="qty">10</td>
      <td id="area">250</td>
      <td id="price">16.50</td>
      <td id="total">160.50</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td id="name"">DRY FOODS</td>
      <td id="qty">5</td>
      <td id="area">100</td>
      <td id="price">10.25</td>
      <td id="total">51.25</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td id="name">FRESH</td>
      <td id="qty">20</td>
      <td id="area">250</td>
      <td id="price">5</td>
      <td id="total">100</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td id="name">MEAT</td>
      <td id="qty">10</td>
      <td id="area">250</td>
      <td id="price">15</td>
      <td id="total">150</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td id="name">FROZEN</td>
      <td id="qty">20</td>
      <td id="area">300</td>
      <td id="price">10</td>
      <td id="total">200</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

So, I want to make an array like `{area:total}` then grouping array values based on area and sum area values.

Like :
**AREA 250** : 410.5
**AREA 100** : 51.25
**AREA 300** : 200

I tried as follow which I got it array but I don't know how can I grouping the areas ( I used setInterval function because employees can remove or change the area values)

```
            setInterval(function() {
            var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
            var sasData = [];
            $row.each(function(i) {
                var sasValue = parseFloat($row.find("#area").val());
                var totValue = parseFloat($row.find("#total").val());
                sasData.push({sas:sasValue, tot:totValue});
                console.log(sasData);
            });

            function compressedArray(original) {
                var compressed = [];
            };
        }, 1500)
```

Could you please show me the way how can we handle this issue?

Comment: you forgot to close your `<thead>`-tag

Comment: @StefanFandler—the closing tag for [thead](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-THEAD) is optional. But the markup is invalid because thead can only have tr as child elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This JSFiddle should solve your problem. I've also fixed your missing thead, your double quote in the *DRY FOODS* td, and changes id's to classes:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q9nrf/1/

```
var areas = {};
$("tr").each(function() {
    var area = $(this).find("td.area").text();
    if (area != "") {
        var total = parseFloat($(this).find("td.total").text());
        if (!areas.hasOwnProperty(area)) {
            areas[area] = 0;            
        }
        areas[area] += total;
    }
});
console.log(areas);
```

Comment: I have one more question, if we have more than one table in the page, how can we pass this table in `$("tr")` function?

Comment: What you could simply do is give the table a class (or an ID) and use the selector `$("#mytable tr")`. Here's a JSFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/Q9nrf/5/

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the id values to some other attribute, say class.

Loop over the rows (use the tbody element to skip the header) and collect values from the elements with the classes you're after. You will need to use an array to store them, as you can't order the properties of an object and each property must have a unique name.

Answer (score 1):

id should be **unique**. so change `<td id="area">250</td>` to `<td class="area">250</td>`

then just call:

```
o = {};
$("td.area").each(function(){ 
 key = o[$(this).text()];
 if (!key) key = 0;
 key += parseFloat( $(this).closest("tr").find(".total").text());
});
```

then you have on object contains key-value [key=area code, value=total]

Comment: Correction: Ids should ideally be unique, but they _don't have to_ be. This is apparent from the forgiveness of modern day browsers. Scoped queries like $el.find("#someid") _do_ work, even if the ids are not unique.

Comment: Good solution, but please store the outcome of `$(this).text()` in a local variable.

Comment: Remember to use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`, as the OP has floating numbers.